# Remove text from TextArea and insert new data into it using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In this program, when I type in the textarea then it should delete the textarea value and then update its value to 'hello world', but its not working. If I type c key then it should show the 'Hello world', but it  is showing 'Hello worldc' with the c key that I typed.

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('.textarea');

textArea.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
 textArea.value = '';
 textArea.value = 'Hello world';
});
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textArea.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
```

Use KeyUp Event